# How to work with this data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to get a particular object inside an array of objects.

```
var arr = [
           {
             id: "asd"
             description: "V1", 
             output: [{type: "A", id:"ge"}]
           },
           {
             id: "qwe"
             description: "V2", 
             output: [{type: "B", id:"de"}]
           }
          ];

console.log(arr.description);
```

and

```
console.log(arr.output.type);
```

The desired output would be:

```
 {
    { description: "V1", output: {type: "A", id: "ge"}},
    { description: "V2", output: {type: "B", id: "de"}}
 }
```

and also I would like to convert the `'output'` array of an object into an object just like the output. How to achieve this?

Help me here

Comment: array are indexed, you need to access them like this `arr[0]` will give you `{ id:"asd", description: "V1", output: {type:"A", id "ge"}}`

Comment: "*I'm not 100% sure whether the desired output is in the right format*'. **You** specify what the desired output *should* be. What exactly are you trying to achieve, and how do you think the above output will help you achieve it?

Comment: So you've tried nothing and you're all out of ideas.

Comment: `arr` and `output`s are arrays, you have to use a subscript to access their elements: `arr[0]` is the first object, `arr[1]` is the second. `arr[0].output` is the `output` array of the first object in `arr`, `arr[0].output[0].type` is the `type` of the first object in the `output` of the first object in `arr`, ...

Comment: @wilomGfx - I'm not getting an output.

Comment: @Obsidin - I'm now sure that's the output I desire. I have edited the question. I'm getting this data from a collection, so I was lil bit unsure of the output. Now its clear

Answer (score 1):

at the first you have an small mistake in your array syntax.
it most be:

```
var arr = [
       {
         id: "asd",
         description: "V1", 
         output: [{type: "A", id:"ge"}]
       },
       {
         id: "qwe",
         description: "V2", 
         output: [{type: "B", id:"de"}]
       }
      ];
```

if you just want log it you can use this:

```
arr.forEach(function(item){console.log(item.description)})
```

this code:
for each object in `arr` array do:
set name of that object to `item`
and finally log `description` in `item`

you can use this code in other form

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Your desired `output` isn't valid JSON syntax to begin with...

Assuming that `output` only contains an array of length 1. You could do:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i]['output'] = arr[i]['output'][0];
    }
```

This would remove the array notation from your original.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the items removing the outer array, you can do this:

```js
var arr = [
   {
     id: "asd",
     description: "V1", 
     output: [{type: "A", id:"ge"}]
   },
   {
     id: "qwe",
     description: "V2", 
     output: [{type: "B", id:"de"}]
   }
];

for (let item of arr) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to remove the array notation for the value of `item.output` ?

Comment: You can call `toString()` on it or you loop over it like I did for the outer array or simply index it using `output[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your array first, then the arrays in the `output` value. Note that I chose to use [**spread syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to copy over from your original `output` objects to avoid mutation:

```js
var arr = [{
    id: "asd",
    description: "V1",
    output: [{
      type: "A",
      id: "ge"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "qwe",
    description: "V2",
    output: [{
      type: "B",
      id: "de"
    }]
  }
];

const objArr = [];

arr.forEach(obj => {
  obj['output'].forEach(obj => {
    objArr.push({ ...obj });
  });
});

console.log(objArr);
```